# Reading JSON file that is an array in C# with unknown keys

Tags: c#, json

I am having trouble reading from this JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "id":"100",
    "name": "myname",
    "playlists": {
       "unknown key": ["song 1", "song2"]
    }
  }
]
```

here is my guild class:

```
public class Guild{
  public string id = "";
  public string name = "";
  public Dictionary<string, List<string>> playlists;
  

  public Guild(string name, string id, Dictionary<string, List<string>> playlists){
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;
    this.playlists = playlists;
  }
}
```

Im having trouble reading from this JSON file because of the unknown keys and the array that surrounds the entire JSON file. Can someone please help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: An array surrounding a file just needs you to deser to an array of Guild e.g. `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Guild[]>`

Comment: For those annoying scenarios where the keys of an object are all over the place, it's easiest to deser it to a `Dictionary<string,Whatever>` then you can run over the dictionary after picking out keys of interest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using [fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields). Traditionally you should use [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties):

```
public class Guild {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public Dictionary<string, List<string>> playlists { get; set; }
}
```

But the primary problem is that you need to deserialize into a `List<Guild>` or `Guild[]` since the input JSON is an array of `Guild`.

```
var guilds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Guild>>(inputJson);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 6, you could directly use `JsonArray` from [System.Text.Json.Nodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.nodes). For instance, to get first `unknown key`:

```cs
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

var json_string = @"
[
  {
    ""id"":""100"",
    ""name"": ""myname"",
    ""playlists"": {
      ""unknown key"": [""song 1"", ""song2""]
    }
  }
]
";

var guild = JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(JsonNode.Parse(json_string)) as JsonArray;
var firstUnknownKey = guild[0]["playlists"]["unknown key"][0];
WriteLine(firstUnknownKey); // Prints: song 1
```